# Query Custom Post Type by Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, taxonomy

I've created a query working fine pulling posts from a specific taxonomy—but before I had only 7 taxonomies that were permanent, now I have sub taxonomies under that main taxonomy and they will be dynamic.

Any ideas of how I might be able to write this but have a for-each loop going through this query for any taxonomy that is a child of the main taxonomy (in this example the parent taxonomy is 'Cameras')

So again: I have 7 parent taxonomies ('Cameras' is one) and each one has a dynamic amount of sub taxonomies, i'm trying to create a for each loop that will allow me to do the following without writing the query for each specific sub-taxonomy.

Thanks

```
<h2>Cameras</h2>
<ul>
<?  $args = array(
                                'post_type'=> 'rental_gear',
                                'type'    => 'cameras',
                                'order'    => 'ASC',
                                'posts_per_page' => '-1'
                                );              

                            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

                            ?>
                            <li class="equip-li"><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">&rsaquo; <? the_title(); ?></a></li>  
                            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_terms/) with `child_of` (accepts numerical ID of parent term) argument to retrieve child terms and then loop through them and on each iteration use current term in the loop.

Code example (not tested):

```
$child_terms = get_terms( array( 'child_of' => $cameras_term_id ) );

foreach( $child_terms as $term ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'rental_gear',
        'type'    => $term->term_slug,
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );              

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        ?><li class="equip-li"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">&rsaquo; <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>  
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

}
```

Comment: Are you saying to use get_terms() in the query loop? I need to do the same markup as you see here repeatedly, I need to list the permalink / title in an <li> for each post within that child_of term

Comment: @RooWM no, outside of it. Then each iteration of will have same loop with changing child term (if I understood right what you want to achieve).

Comment: I think I see what you're saying—do you mind showing me? I'm not sure how to incorporate the current term once it is found